# Why does get_post() return the latest post inside template_include before doing anything

Tags: get-post, template-include

Assume all the code below is in a theme's `function.php`

If I add `get_post()` at the top, It'd get `null`, which is totally expected since I'm not in the loop, or nothing has been done.

But I add

```
add_filter('template_include', 'call_get_post'));

function call_get_posT(){
 var_dump(get_post())
}
```

Then I'll get the info for the latest `post`.

I tried this in a fresh install of WP locally so I'd assume this is expected behavior, but I don't understand it. I'm not in the loop, and I haven't called anything to start a query, why would `get_post()` return the first post? Same result if I use `global $post`.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried this in a fresh install of WP locally so I'd assume this is expected behavior, but I don't understand it. I'm not in the loop,

No but that doesn't mean a main query doesn't exist, it just means your code to display it hasn't run yet

> and I haven't called anything to start a query,

But the main query has started and completed, it needs to in order for conditionals used to decide which template to load to work.

> why would get_post() return the first post? Same result if I use global $post.

Why wouldn't it? Note that you get the same result because they are literally the same thing.

When you load a URL several things happen:

- the pretty URL gets matched against a rule that turns it into an ugly URL aka `index.php?foo=bar`
- those URL parameters get whitelisted and fed into the main query `WP_Query`, which is what the main loop functions operate on.
- that query is used to power functions like `is_single` or `is_archive` etc
- WP uses those functions to make a decision about which theme template or block template to load.

So the main query has already fetched the posts, and the first post is already available. **If it wasn't, there'd be no way to catch 404s or load page templates for pages.**

Ofcourse, you've not called `the_post()` yet which might be why there's some confusion, but that makes more sense if you know these things:

- if you don't tell `get_post` which post to get, it defaults to the current post, aka `global $post`. It's the very first thing it does in the function

  - if you call this too early it can return `null`
- In the main WP class there's a function named `register_globals` that sets up initial values for major globals, including `$post`, which at the time of writing has a line that looks like this: `$GLOBALS['post']         = isset( $wp_query->post ) ? $wp_query->post : null;`

  - it too will set it to `null` if no posts were found to avoid problems

Remember, ***all*** frontend pages have a main query, even if you use `get_posts` or `new WP_Query` in your templates.

Comment: That's a fantastic answer, thank you!

Is there a way to differentiate if the $post is coming from the initialized query or if the request is actually for that post?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you give an example of when those two situations might not be the same?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress queries the correct posts from the database automatically on every page load based on the URL. It needs to do that to know which template to load. Part of this process involves initialising the global `$post` variable to the first post found (or last, I can’t remember right now which one it will be). On single posts this will be the only post.

You don’t need to initiate any query yourself for WordPress to query posts. If fact, if you're manually querying posts for the main list of posts on your blog page (or category archive etc.) you're doing it wrong. The purpose of the standard loop is to simply loop through those posts so that they can be displayed.

Comment: this is crazy counter intuitive, and I couldn't find this explanation nowhere in the docs (prob didn't read the correct ones but anyway). Thanks.